# Economics of clubs(sport gym, language course, etc)

Tags: reference-request, preferences

I am looking for economic research, theory or empirics, on production/profit maximization/competition for firms producing goods with network effects, such as clubs in which every one's utility depends on the number of other participants. As a producer, my goal is not only to produce the good, but to ensure that enough people consume it at the same time.

What are key papers in this area? What are keywords for me to search for Relevant papers?

Answer (score 1):

No doubt there are other topics that have network effects, but one place to look is spatial common pool or pollution literature, where actions in location A have an effect in location B, and some coordination is required.

Papers include renewable resources e.g.:

> Kaffine, Daniel T., and Christopher Costello. "Unitization of
>   spatially connected renewable resources." The BE Journal of Economic
>   Analysis & Policy 11.1 (2011).
>   https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/bejeap.2011.11.issue-1/bejeap.2011.11.1.2714/bejeap.2011.11.1.2714.xml

The acid rain problem (admittedly quite old):

> Mäler, Karl-Göran, and Aart De Zeeuw. "The acid rain differential
>   game." Environmental and Resource Economics 12.2 (1998): 167-184.
>   https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008273509255

And things like pollen dispersal (self-promotion, but it is definitely clubs):

> Punt, Maarten J., and Justus Wesseler. "The Formation of GM‐free and
>   GM Coasean Clubs: Will They Form and If So How Much Can They
>   Achieve?." Journal of Agricultural Economics 69.2 (2018): 413-438.
>   https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1477-9552.12235